# Cannot take complete ownership of registry keys using psexec

Tags: windows-10, regedit

I am running Windows 10 OS, where some registry keys are out of my reach even after running `regedit` using `psexec`. Please let me know how can I take complete ownership and edit these keys? *I am aware of the risks and know what I am doing here*

I have followed the steps given below:

1. Open command prompt as administrator
2. Run command `psexec -s -i c:\windows\regedit.exe`
3. Confirm that it is running under SYSTEM account
   [image]
4. Change ownership of the registry folder
   [image]

**EDIT**
As the comment suggests, I need to use an offline registry editor. But, I couldn't find any article on how to do this on Windows 10.

Comment: Best bet is to use an offline registry editor.

Comment: Which key are you trying to change ownership for? Is this happening for all registry branches.

Comment: If I understand right, this is part of the Sophos Anti-Virus, which might itself be preventing the change. Try to do it while booting in Safe Mode, to disable Sophos.

Comment: A stronger measure is needed. See [How to edit & modify the Windows Registry OFFLINE](https://www.wintips.org/how-to-edit-and-modify-registry-offline/),

Comment: A USB will work as well.

Comment: Why are you trying to disable Sophos Antivirus (AV) via this method instead of through the interface via their guides: [home ver](https://support.home.sophos.com/hc/en-us/articles/360040462632-How-to-temporarily-disable-Sophos-Home-to-troubleshoot-issues-) & [endpoint ver](https://support.sophos.com/support/s/article/KB-000034808?language=en_US)? Google searching this will get you more help: [`disable site:sophos.com`](https://www.google.com/search?q=disable+site%3Asophos.com). AV is designed to prevent this behavior as it can be interpreted as an attack/virus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was finally able to change the registry keys using an offline registry editor method as stated in the comments for the question. The way to do it in Windows 10 is described at https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/edit-registry-offline-windows-re/

I will write the summary below for someone who needs this in future. Keep your Bit Defender recovery key ready if you have encrypted your disk.

1. Go to windows recovery options by keeping the `shift` key pressed while clicking on the restart option from the start menu.
2. Click on `Troubleshoot` > `Advanced Options` > `Command Prompt`
3. Enter the Bit Defender recovery key if asked.
4. After command prompt is loaded run `regedit`
5. Load registry hive using `File` > `Load hive`
6. Select the hive and make required registry modifications
7. Unload the hive and restart the machine.

Although I was not able to take ownership of the registry key, I was able to change it which was the final aim of taking the ownership.

Comment: The question remains: why? The Sophos software itself allows you to disable it. Except if it has been locked down by an admin. And even then there are some funky workarounds against which SAV is helpless (involving reboot, but no offline editing of the registry).

Comment: Your admin may be somewhat unhappy and if this is in a company context you may even be violating IT policies. Sophos AV is impertinent, I know (had it prescribed for ~2 years as an employee myself), but be careful.

Comment: I hear you! Sophos is rather intrusive and the most important aspect for me wasn't to disable the filter driver or AV service, but to get rid of HitMan Pro which came bundled with the Sophos "endpoint protection" solution that was on my machine. After that it was mostly bearable.